# Async patterns in flutter/dart: Any downsides to async/await vs. raw Future API?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

What is the best way to deal with Futures in Flutter/Dart applications. Dealing with the raw Future api, or using async functions with await? Are there any pros/cons or is it all up to personal preference?

It seems the [AngularDart Project has tried to get rid](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1010) of async/await due to the complexities of the generated javascript code. Which is obviously not a concern for Flutter applications. But sometimes I think the expressiveness (and imho functional style) of the Future api has advantages over dealing with async functions.

Are there any technical reasons to avoid the async/await sugar in favor of directly dealing with Future api? (fwiw I have also tried to get some feedback on this from the [flutter-dev mailing list without success](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/flutter-dev/async%7Csort:date/flutter-dev/fkI0lbAYZqU/0dTcEt4wBgAJ)).

Comment: check [here](https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling): `Why would you use the Future API instead of async and await?`

Comment: @pskink because i like the functional style most of the time.. for example when writing a small function like `Future<Result> findResult() => compute().then((result) => result.doSomething()).then((result2) => result2.doSomethingElse()))` seems to be nicer than `await (await ((await compute()).doSomething())).doSomethingElse()`

Answer (score 2):

The Future class (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-async/Future-class.html) supports `any` and `wait`, which would be impossible to replicate with the sequential nature of `await`. But for the 80% of the use-cases, `await` probably suffices.

Comment: Async/await is what we recommend in [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures)

Comment: Yes, async/await is much cleaner to read, but I was pointing out the rare cases where it would not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is any technical reason to avoid Async/await. The documentation treats them the same except for the way you write the results. This is a personal preference thing. To me, if you have multiple futures in a sequence the Async/await format is easier to follow.